# how to adjust class_weight of GaussianNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I have a slightly unbalanced data set (arount 200 more datapoints in class 1 than in class 2) and I want to solve that via setting the parameter `class_weight='balanced'`. It worked perfectly with `LogisticRegression` model and with the `DecisionTree` model of sklearn like so:

```
decisiontree = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
```

I want to do the exact same thing with sklearns `GaussianNB` but the parameter `class_weight` is not supported there.
How could I do that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is your dataset? It's probably unnecessary to balance it...

Comment: its not that big, couple of hundreds of data points for each class. but i would like to do it accurately either way :)

Comment: It's not about accuracy, your dataset just doesn't sounds particularly imbalanced. What percentage of the full dataset would you say your positive class is?